# How to convert serial data from 8 bit controller and show it in asci?

Tags: c, serial-port, int, pic, uart

I'm in to embedded coding and i have a problem here.I'm using uart communication and want to send integers over the serial line.each integer must be shown as character in ascii.What all things should i be careful of?.
The data from controller side will be in integer/char/float format.What should i need to take care of while dealing with displaying those data from controller on a serial monitoring s/w?.
I'm coding in c language

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is converting integers to ascii there is a standard compliant way to do it.

```
sprintf(str, "%d", your_integer);
```

Comment: I m doubtful about the prospect of having that function in the compiler which i am using now.Im using c18 compiler of microchip

Comment: This function is in the standard of the C language so it should be. If not tell me and I will figure out another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to send/receive data with UART communication using micro controller such as 8051. 
So here are the things you should be looking at.

1) What is the Baud rate you want to send with? [Baud rate is number of symbols transmitted/received per second]

2) How many bits you want to receive per symbol? [Depends on how many bit micro controller do you use]

Here is the code sample for UART communication to send "STACK OVERFLOW" with 9600 Baud rate with 8 bit data for 8051. [From the book "The 8051 Microcontroller and Embedded Systems"]

```
#include <reg51.h>
void SerTx(unsigned char);
void main(void){
TMOD=0x20; //use Timer 1, mode 2
TH1=0xFD; //9600 baud rate
SCON=0x50;
TR1=1; //start timer
while (1) {
SerTx(‘S’);SerTx(‘T’);SerTx(‘A’);SerTx(‘C’);SerTx(‘K’);
SerTx(‘’);SerTx(‘O’);SerTx(‘V’);SerTx(‘E’);SerTx(‘R’);
SerTx(‘F’);SerTx(‘L’);SerTx(‘O’);SerTx(‘W’);
}}
void SerTx(unsigned char x){
SBUF=x; //place value in buffer
while (TI==0); //wait until transmitted
TI=0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare:

`unsigned char array[10] = {'F','E','E','D','B','A','B','E','C','A',};`

the compiler puts it into a proper digital representation according to the ASCII table (see it below). So on your device side it is like `0x46` for `'F'`, `0x45` for `'E'` and etc. When you send it through the serial by passing by this array to TX function it will go to the other side with same codes, again like `0x46` for `'F'`, `0x45` for `'E'` and etc.

When you put it straight in digital, like here it will remain the values as is.

`unsigned char array2[10] = {0xFE,0xED,0xBA,0xBE,0xDE,0xAD,0xBE,0xEF,0xCA,0xFE};`

You can transfer actually any data as binary, it is a question of representation sometimes in particular place.

[image]